# C++: Why must I order my declaration as a double in this manner?

Tags: c++, initialization, expression, control-flow

so one of my assignments was to make a program that converts currencies, this one below converts U.S. dollars to certain south american dollars.

I'm not sure why I can't declare a variable for US dollars along with the variable for the other currencies. I did it this way, and the program screwed up the conversion:

```
double dollars;

double pesos = dollars * 26;

double reais = dollars * 5.9;

double soles = dollars * 3.53;

std::cout << "Enter the number of U.S. dollars you have:";
std::cin >> dollars;

std::cout << "In colombian pesos, that's " << pesos << "\n";
std::cout << "In brazilean reals, that's " << reais << "\n";
std::cout << "In peruvian soles, that's " << soles << "\n";
```

the input/output was this:

```
Enter the number of U.S. dollars you have:1
In colombian pesos, that's 0
In brazilean reals, that's 0
In peruvian soles, that's 0
```

However, when i run the code this way (putting the input directly after the declaration of `dollars`), the input performs the correct conversion:

```
double dollars;

std::cout << "Enter the number of U.S. dollars you have:";
std::cin >> dollars;

double pesos = dollars * 26;

double reais = dollars * 5.9;

double soles = dollars * 3.53;

std::cout << "In colombian pesos, that's " << pesos << "\n";
std::cout << "In brazilean reals, that's " << reais << "\n";
std::cout << "In peruvian soles, that's " << soles << "\n";
```

I didn't think where i place the declaration of the variable mattered, as long as i declared it before using it.

Comment: You have to enter `dollars` before you can calculate `pesos` from it, etc.

Comment: Move `std::cin >> dollars;` up, right before the other currencies deceleration. Just noticed you already realized that. It's because `dollars` is uninitialized, with unknown value in it.

Comment: This code [should elicit a warning from the compiler](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/6c8Pq9). Please adjust your compiler warnings to make that happen.

Comment: This is because a statement in c++ is not a mathematical relationship it's a one time calculation. In your first example you calculate the value of `pesos`, `reais` and `soles` before you asked for the `dollars` using whatever garbage was in the uninitialized `dollars` variable.

Comment: Tony Tannous, that was the type of response i was looking for, thank you. It appears that i can't assign the value later, i just was thinking that `double dollar;` was merely a placeholder and could be assigned the value later.

Comment: @Novelty C++ has value semantics. The `=` operator copies the immediate value of the right operand to the left operand. It does not declare an equality or relationship.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Expression in declarations are calculated immediately

The following statements initialize **variables** using an expression calculated immediately with `dollars` **as it is know at that exact moment**:

```
double pesos = dollars * 26;
double reais = dollars * 5.9;
double soles = dollars * 3.53;
```

It's not like Excel formulas that would be recalculated based on the latest known value.  This is why:

- in the first case the calculation is made before the user input.  You may see the weird results because `dollars` was not yet initialized. By the way,  better initialize the variables that you declare.
- in the second case, the calculation is made after user input of `dollars` and therefore provides the result that you expect.

### Functions can calculate the expression when you need it

If you want to define a general formula to make the calculation without making the calculation immediately,  you should define **functions**:

```
double pesos(double dollars) {return dollars * 26;}
double reais(double dollars) {return  dollars * 5.9;}
double soles(double dollars) {return  dollars * 3.53;}
```

Each of these functions use an expression that will be calculated at the moment the function is called.  The calculation will use the `dollar` value  passed as parameter.  For example:

```
std::cout << "In mexican pesos, that's " << pesos(dollars) << "\n";
std::cout << "In brazilean reals, that's " << reais(dollars) << "\n";
std::cout << "In peruvian soles, that's " << soles(dollars) << "\n";
```

You can call the same function several times, to always get up-to-date calculation based on the parameter provided:

```
std::cout << "3.14 dollars in brazilean reals is " << reais(3.14) << "\n";
std::cout << "500/3 dollars in brazilean reals is " << reais(500.0/3.0) << "\n";
double another_value=0.0;  
std::cin >> another_value; 
std::cout << another_value << "dollars in brazilean reals is " << reais(another_value) << std::endl;
```